# Por que al utilizar "document.getElementsByClassName" el borde no cambia?

Tags: javascript

Si en vez de utilizar “document.getElementsByClassName”, utilizo “document.getElementById” y le asigno un Id al , en ese caso si funciona, que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
function resalta(elEvento) {
  var evento = elEvento || window.event;
  switch(evento.type) {
    case 'mouseover':
      this.style.borderColor = 'red';
      break;
    case 'mouseout':
      this.style.borderColor = 'green';
      break;
  }
}
 
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("texto").onmouseover = resalta;
  document.getElementsByClassName("texto").onmouseout = resalta;
}
```

```css
.texto{
    height:60px;
    width: 150px;
    border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="css/estilos.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/codigo.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="texto">¡¡¡ANUNCIO!!!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿cuáles son los acciones reales que quieres realizar cuando se pase/salga el ratón sobre el elemento?

Answer (score 5):

No funciona porque `getElementsByClassName` devuelve un objeto similar a un array, por lo cual no se puede aplicar directamente `onmouseover` como si fuera un elemento único.

Un poco de documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Tendrías que iterar a través de dicho objeto si deseas hacer "algo" con cada uno de sus elementos.

Aquí va una solución rápida, tal vez no muy limpia:

```js
function resalta(e) {
  var evento = e || window.event;
  switch(evento.type) {
    case 'mouseover':
      e.target.style.borderColor = 'red';
      break;
    case 'mouseout':
      e.target.style.borderColor = 'green';
      break;
  }
}
 
window.onload = function() {
  var textos = document.getElementsByClassName("texto");

  for (var i=0, len=textos.length; i<len; i++) { 
    textos[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        resalta(e);
    });
    textos[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
        resalta(e);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.texto{
    height:60px;
    width: 150px;
    border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="css/estilos.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/codigo.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="texto">¡¡¡ANUNCIO!!!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Shaz, ahora por que en la función "resalta", cambiaste "this.style.borderColor" y utilizaste un evento "target"?. si me fijo bien con this, en este caso no me funciona, pero no entiendo muy bien la razón.

Comment: Dicha función está recibiendo el objeto del "evento", y en la propiedad `target` está almacenado el objeto que activó el evento, el cual en este caso es el mismo al que le vamos a cambiar el estilo. Aquí puedes ver algo de documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Answer (score 0):

Si accedes al elemento usando getElementsByClassName, y como es posible esperar varios elementos con la misma clase([0],[1],[2]...), tienes que definir cual de ellos vas a usar, en este caso y como sólo tienes un elemento con clase "texto" deberías elegir el elemento [0] del array como bien ha respondido @Shaz.

Si te fijas, get"ELEMENTS"ByClassName, da a entender que espera más de un elemento.

Sería algo así:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var texto1 = document.getElementsByClassName("texto");
  texto1[0].addEventListener(......
}
```